# Why doesn't update_attribute change my timestamp column

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model with a timestamp column, queued_at.

Why doesn't `update_attribute(:queued_at, Time.now)` write to the database?  This only happens occasionally.  This is a frequently updated attribute.  update_column seems to work all the time.

I'm using rails 3.2.12 with postgres.

This problem does not exist in rails 3.1.11.

These projects demonstrate the "problems":

1. https://github.com/johnnaegle/scratch/tree/feature/rails_3.2.12
2. https://github.com/johnnaegle/scratch/tree/feature/rails_3.1.11

Comment: If you are experience this, its a bug in rails that is fixed in the next (after 3.2.12) non-security release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `update_attribute` only sees a change if the current time and the new time your are trying to set differ by at least a second.  I couldn't find where in the activerecord code this happens, but this demonstrates the problem.  I create two times, 100ms appart, update a record with the first time, but the second update doesn't commit to the database.

```
[15] pry(main)> x=Time.now;sleep(0.1);y=Time.now
=> 2013-02-20 12:06:57 -0600

[16] pry(main)> x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
=> "2013-02-20 12:06:57.185"

[17] pry(main)> y.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
=> "2013-02-20 12:06:57.286"

[18] pry(main)> kat = Kitten.first
  Kitten Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "kittens".* FROM "kittens" LIMIT 1
=> #<Kitten id: 1,  queued_at: "2013-02-13 20:38:00">

[19] pry(main)> kat.queued_at = x
=> 2013-02-20 12:06:57 -0600

[20] pry(main)> kat.save
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.6ms)  UPDATE "kittens" SET "queued_at" = '2013-02-20 18:06:57.185870' WHERE "kittens"."id" = 1
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
=> true

[21] pry(main)> kat.queued_at = y
=> 2013-02-20 12:06:57 -0600

[22] pry(main)> kat.save
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
=> true
```

Comment: I would love to know why and where ActiveRecord decides that the object isn't changed for the second update.

Comment: FWIW, this test doesn't work for my rails 3.1.11 project.

The second save does write to the database.

Comment: I started a clean rails 3.1.11 project and the second save did write.  After upgrading it to 3.2.12, it didn't commit.  Wheeeeee!  Riding the rails.

Comment: PG Adapter problem maybe? What are the versions for the adapter on 3.1 and 3.2?

Answer (score 3):

It appears active_record is smart enough to know if the value being updating is the same or close enough (in the case of timestamps) it will avoid the SQL write - a performance saving.  I have had success forcing the updated_at field to be written by "touching" the model of the object in question after the update_attribute call

```
foo.update_attribute :last_status, status
foo.touch
## log entry
##  UPDATE `foo` SET `updated_at` = '2013-07-25 19:56:36' WHERE `foo`.`id` = 55
```

Comment: You can also use update_column to force a write regardless of what the model thinks is dirty.  That won't change updated_at as a side affect.